Neptune gremlin query times out
I have a Neptune cluster and I am using Gremlin for my queries.
I have a query where it traverses nodes and adds other nodes connected to it.
The issue is when I run this through the Notebook it runs very fast and succeeds but when I run it through my lambda function it gets stuck and never ends the query.
My query is similar to below:
 await this.g
  .V(communicationId)
  .as("communication")
  .outE()
  .inV()
  .hasLabel(TemplateVertex.name)
  .outE()
  .inV()
  .where(process.P.neq("communication"))
  .where(process.P.eq("communication"))
  .by("channel")
  .as("content")
  .V(communicationId)
  .outE()
  .inV()
  .hasLabel(Segment.name)
  .as("segment")
  .repeat(
    process.statics
      .outE()
      .inV()
      .hasLabel(Person.name)
      .as("person")
      .addV(NotificationVertex.name)
      .as("notification")
      .addE("sent")
      .from_("notification")
      .to("person")
      .addE(EdgeLabels.HAS)
      .from_("communication")
      .to("notification")
      .addE(EdgeLabels.WITH_CONTENT)
      .from_("notification")
      .to("content")
      .outV(),
  )
  .until(process.statics.not(process.statics.out().hasLabel(Person.name)))
  .iterate();

and the similar for the notebook is:
%%gremlin 
g
.V("some-id")
.as("communication")
.outE()
.inV()
.hasLabel("TemplateVertex")
.outE()
.inV()
.where(neq('communication')).where(eq('communication')).by('channel')
.as("content")
.V("some-id")
.outE()
.inV()
.hasLabel("Segment")
.as("segment")
.repeat(
    outE()
    .hasLabel("SegmentToPerson")
    .inV()
    .hasLabel("Person")
    .as("person")
    .addV("Notification")
    .as("notification")
    .addE("sent")
    .from("notification")
    .to("person")
    .addE("Has")
    .from("communication")
    .to("notification")
    .addE("withContent")
    .from("notification")
    .to("content")
    .outV()
)
.until(not(out().hasLabel("Person")))
.iterate()

The result of running the first one in notebook with profile is:
*******************************************************
                Neptune Gremlin Profile
*******************************************************

Query String
==================
g
      .V("ebade673-18b1-4ee7-871a-3d140460d29e")
      .as("communication")
      .outE()
      .inV()
      .hasLabel("TemplateVertex")
      .outE()
      .inV()
      .where(neq("communication"))
      .where(eq("communication"))
      .by("channel")
      .as("content")
      .V("ebade673-18b1-4ee7-871a-3d140460d29e")
      .outE()
      .inV()
      .hasLabel("Segment")
      .as("segment")
      .repeat(
          outE()
          .inV()
          .hasLabel("Person")
          .as("person")
          .addV("NotificationVertex")
          .as("notification")
          .addE("HAS")
          .from("communication")
          .to("notification")
          .addE("WITH_CONTENT")
          .from("notification")
          .to("content")
          .addE("sent")
          .from("person")
          .to("notification")
          .outV()
      )
      .until(not(out().hasLabel("Person")))
      .elementMap()


Original Traversal
==================
[GraphStep(vertex,[ebade673-18b1-4ee7-871a-3d140460d29e])@[communication], VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), HasStep([~label.eq(TemplateVertex)]), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), WherePredicateStep(null,neq(communication)), WherePredicateStep(null,eq(communication),[value(channel)])@[content], GraphStep(vertex,[ebade673-18b1-4ee7-871a-3d140460d29e]), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), HasStep([~label.eq(Segment)])@[segment], RepeatStep([VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), HasStep([~label.eq(Person)])@[person], AddVertexStep({label=[NotificationVertex]})@[notification], AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,communication,null)]], label=[HAS], ~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)]]}), AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)]], label=[WITH_CONTENT], ~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,content,null)]]}), AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,person,null)]], label=[sent], ~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)]]}), EdgeVertexStep(OUT), RepeatEndStep],until([NotStep([VertexStep(OUT,vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Person)])])]),emit(false)), ElementMapStep]

Profile Time: 2024-07-22T16:03:05.208
Engine Version: 1.3.2.1.R1

Optimized Traversal
===================
Neptune steps:
[
    NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex)@[communication] {
        JoinGroupNode {
            PatternNode[VL(?3, <~label>, ?4=<TemplateVertex>, <~>) . project ?3 .], {estimatedCardinality=14, expectedTotalOutput=14, indexTime=0, joinTime=2, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=14}
            PatternNode[EL(?1=<ebade673-18b1-4ee7-871a-3d140460d29e>, ?5, ?3, ?6) . project ?1,?3 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?6) .], {estimatedCardinality=28, expectedTotalInput=14, indexTime=5, hashJoin=true, expectedTotalOutput=1, joinTime=0, actualTotalOutput=1}
            PatternNode[EL(?3, ?9, ?7, ?10) . project ?3,?7 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?10) . CompareFilter(?7 != ?1) .], {estimatedCardinality=INFINITY, expectedTotalInput=1, indexTime=0, joinTime=2, numSearches=1}
        }, {path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep@[communication], Vertex(?3):VertexStep, Vertex(?7):VertexStep], joinStats=true, optimizationTime=186, readForUpdate=true, maxVarId=11, executionTime=781}
    },
    NeptuneTraverserConverterStep
]
+ not converted into Neptune steps: WherePredicateStep(null,eq(communication),[value(channel)])@[content],GraphStep(vertex,[ebade673-18b1-4ee7-871a-3d140460d29e]),VertexStep(OUT,vertex),NeptuneHasStep([~label.eq(Segment)])@[segment],RepeatStep([NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep, VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NeptuneHasStep([~label.eq(Person)])@[person], AddVertexStep({label=[NotificationVertex]})@[notification], AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,communication,null)]], label=[HAS], ~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)]]}), AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)]], label=[WITH_CONTENT], ~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,content,null)]]}), AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,person,null)]], label=[sent], ~to=[[SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)]]}), EdgeVertexStep(OUT), RepeatEndStep],until([NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep, NotStep([VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NeptuneHasStep([~label.eq(Person)])])]),emit(false)),ElementMapStep,

WARNING: >> [WherePredicateStep(null,eq(communication),[value(channel)])@[content]] << (or one of the children for each step) is not supported natively yet

Physical Pipeline
=================
NeptuneGraphQueryStep@[communication]
    |-- StartOp
    |-- JoinGroupOp@938e98f
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@60d7cff3(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[VL(?3, <~label>, ?4=<TemplateVertex>, <~>) . project ?3 .], {estimatedCardinality=14, expectedTotalOutput=14}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @60d7cff3, null)
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@5271c8c5(HashJoinOp(PatternNode[EL(?1=<ebade673-18b1-4ee7-871a-3d140460d29e>, ?5, ?3, ?6) . project ?1,?3 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?6) .], {estimatedCardinality=28, expectedTotalInput=14, indexTime=5, hashJoin=true, expectedTotalOutput=1}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @5271c8c5, @60d7cff3)
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@5e980b2f(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[EL(?3, ?9, ?7, ?10) . project ?3,?7 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?10) . CompareFilter(?7 != ?1) .], {estimatedCardinality=INFINITY, expectedTotalInput=1}))

Runtime (ms)
============
Query Execution: 791.921
Serialization:     4.037

Traversal Metrics
=================
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex)@[communication]                          2           2          83.190    11.79
NeptuneTraverserConverterStep                                          2           2           0.172     0.02
WherePredicateStep(null,eq(communication),[valu...                     1           1           3.061     0.43
GraphStep(vertex,[ebade673-18b1-4ee7-871a-3d140...                     1           1           1.566     0.22
VertexStep(OUT,vertex)                                                19          19           3.691     0.52
NeptuneHasStep([~label.eq(Segment)])@[segment]                         1           1         112.589    15.96
RepeatStep([NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep, VertexSte...                     2           2         491.502    69.65
  NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep                                             2           2           0.030
  NotStep([VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NeptuneHasSt...                                             4.948
    VertexStep(OUT,vertex)                                            10          10           1.191
    NeptuneHasStep([~label.eq(Person)])                                                        3.672
  NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep                                             1           1           0.039
  VertexStep(OUT,vertex)                                               2           2           2.904
  NeptuneHasStep([~label.eq(Person)])@[person]                         2           2           1.513
  AddVertexStep({label=[NotificationVertex]})@[...                     2           2         188.392
  AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,commu...                     2           2          23.161
    SelectOneStep(last,communication,null)                             2           2           0.526
    SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)                              2           2           0.055
  AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,notif...                     2           2         162.395
    SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)                              2           2           0.458
    SelectOneStep(last,content,null)                                   2           2           0.053
  AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(last,perso...                     2           2          39.748
    SelectOneStep(last,person,null)                                    2           2           0.020
    SelectOneStep(last,notification,null)                              2           2           0.055
  EdgeVertexStep(OUT)                                                  2           2           0.059
  RepeatEndStep                                                        2           2          73.217
ElementMapStep                                                         2           2           9.881     1.40
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -         705.657        -

Predicates
==========
# of predicates: 39

Results
=======
Count: 2
Output: [{id=khashasa, label=Person, email=khashasa@amazon.com}, {id=ivatang, label=Person, email=ivatang@amazon.com}]
Response serializer: application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json;types=false
Response size (bytes): 261


Index Operations
================
Query execution:
    # of statement index ops: 51
    # of unique statement index ops: 42
    Duplication ratio: 1.21
    # of terms materialized: 5
    # of statements added: 8
    # of statements removed: 0
Serialization:
    # of statement index ops: 51
    # of unique statement index ops: 42
    Duplication ratio: 1.21
    # of terms materialized: 5
    # of statements added: 8
    # of statements removed: 0

I can not understand why one would succeed where the other one timesout.
Thanks in advance for any help

Can you get an explain and profile for notebook query and attach it here please.
Steps to get explain/profile for query can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-explain-api.html

The notebook instance has network connectivity to the instance in the VPC where the cluster is hosted.  Have you defined VPC connectivity for your Lambda function?

@TaylorRiggan the lambda is running in vpc and succeeds the general calls to add vertext and read them. The issue is the never ending query as mentioned

What size instance are you using?  Are there any other queries running at the same time as the query mentioned?  Can you run a Neptune Gremlin Profile (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-profile-api.html) output and attach here?

@TaylorRiggan PrashantUpadhay@ Added the profile result

The notebook would be running the query synchronously.  It appears you are attempting to issue the query asynchronously from within your Lambda function.  Did you intend to do that?  Are you resolving the promise that is getting returned after issuing the query?  The query seems to be executed within ~700ms, which is well below the 2 min default query timeout.  So this appears to be something else going on in your code that is causing the problem.

@TaylorRiggan I understand the sync part and I am awaiting the completion. My issue is exactly as you mentioned, what is different in the query and the lambda query which makes it stuck

Actually, I think I see your issue.  You're using iterate() as a terminal step.  You should really be using either toList() or next().  Iterate() does not return a result.  It is used more for insertion queries.  https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#terminal-steps

@TaylorRiggan You might be right, I also noticed its very important that the final outcome of my repeat should be the same as the starting nodes ("Person")
